# SurfaceView content not visible with FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON activity

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a surfaceview to display MJPEG stream from an IP camera. It's working great except in one case.

On my activity which displays the surfaceview I have following flags:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
```

If I start the activity normally (from the app) it displays the camera picture. But if I start the activity from a background service while the phone is in sleep, the activity is started, the phone is unlocked, the screen is turned on, everything looks good, except there is nothing drawed on the surfaceview. The MJPEG stream is started to receive correctly and It seems to draw it on the canvas, but nothing is displayed. If I rotate the phone, the picture is then displayed, and from this time everything works normally.

I try to put the relevant code pieces here, but if you need something else, I'll put it here also. The MjpegView.class it the class found on the net (also saw the code here on the Stackoverflow), I made some slightly changes in it (mainly in the MjpegInputStream).

The drawing code in a separate thread:

```
while (mRun && mIn != null)
{
    if (surfaceDone)
    {
        try
        {

            try
            {
                bm = mIn.readMjpegFrame();
            }
            catch (IOException e1)
            {
                bm = null;
            }

            if (bm == null) continue;

            c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder)
            {

                destRect = destRect(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());

                c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

                c.drawBitmap(bm, null, destRect, p);

                if (requestscreenshot)
                {
                    requestscreenshot = false;

                    try
                    {
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(requestfile);
                        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // ignore
                    }

                    requestfile = "";
                }

                if (showFps)
                {

                    p.setXfermode(mode);

                    if (ovl != null)
                    {

                        // false indentation to fix forum layout

                        height = ((ovlPos & 1) == 1) ? destRect.top : destRect.bottom - ovl.getHeight();

                        width = ((ovlPos & 8) == 8) ? destRect.left : destRect.right - ovl.getWidth();

                        c.drawBitmap(ovl, width, height, null);

                    }

                    p.setXfermode(null);

                    frameCounter++;

                    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) >= 1000)
                    {

                        fps = String.valueOf(frameCounter) + "fps";

                        frameCounter = 0;

                        start = System.currentTimeMillis();

                        ovl = makeFpsOverlay(overlayPaint);
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        finally
        {
            if (c != null) mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the surfaceview the callbacks:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int f, int w, int h)
{
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "MjpegView.surfaceChanged");
    if (thread != null)
    {
        thread.mSurfaceHolder = holder;
        thread.setSurfaceSize(w, h);
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "MjpegView.surfaceDestroyed");

    surfaceDone = false;

    stopPlayback();
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "MjpegView surfaceCreated");
    surfaceDone = true;
}

public void startPlayback()
{
    if (thread == null)
    {
        thread = new MjpegViewThread(getHolder(), context);
        if (URL != null)
        {
            mRun = true;
            thread.start();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        thread.mSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
    }
}

public void stopPlayback()
{

    mRun = false;

    boolean retry = true;

    while (retry && thread != null)
    {

        try
        {

            thread.join();

            retry = false;

        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }

    }

    thread = null;
}
```

In the activity I use just some initialization in the onCreate:

```
mv.setSource(device.getCameraURL());
mv.setMessageHandler(messageHandler);

mv.setDisplayMode(MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT);

mv.showFps(false);
```

(where mv is the MjpegView)

And in the onResume I call the startPlayback method of the MjpegView

That's it I think.

Appreciate any help! Thanks!

Update:

Might found a work around:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) MjpegtestActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, Constants.TAG);
wl.acquire(); 

Intent intent = new Intent(MjpegtestActivity.this, Camera.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("PLAYSOUND", false);
intent.putExtra("DEVICEID", "a73d3ffd-bebb-aae4-f133-39a81eba6e");
MjpegtestActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

wl.release();
wl = null;
```

If I start the activity after getting a wakelock, the IP camera picture is displayed properly on the surfaceview.

But I don't know why :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, this could be a solution, works from background service also:

```
// start the activity in new thread to allow sleep times
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, Constants.TAG);
        wl.acquire(); 

        try
        {
            // give 500ms for device to wake up
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }


        // start the activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, EntryPhoneControl.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("PLAYSOUND", true);
        intent.putExtra("DEVICEID", dev.getId());
        context.startActivity(intent);

        // wait 5 sec to start the activity before releasing wakelock
        // within 5 sec the activity should be displayed already
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }

        wl.release();
        wl = null;
    }
}).start();
```

So I think this is a quite stable solution.